# If we have fields $K \subseteq E \subseteq F$, and $F$ is a field extension of both $E$ and $K$, is $E$ a field extension of $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

If we have fields $K \subseteq E \subseteq F$, and $F$ is a field extension of both $E$ and $K$ (i.e. both $E$ and $K$ are subfields of $F$, is $E$ a field extension of $K$? This appears obviously true to me but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to show this rigorously.

Comment: What does $K \subseteq E$ mean for you if it doesn't mean "$E$ is a field extension of $K$"? (This is, for example, Wikipedia's definition of a field extension.)

Comment: Fix $x,y\in K$. Then $x+_K y=x+_F y$ since $F$ extends $K$. Also, $x+_F y=x+_E y$ since $F$ extends $E$. So $x+_K y=x+_E y$. This shows that addition in $K$ is the same as addition in $E$. You can make a similar argument for multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is true that $K$ and $E$ are subfields of $F$. In order to prove any field $K$ is field extension of  a field $F$. It is sufficient to show that  there is a function $f$ such that $f:F\to E$ is monomorphism.
For example :$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ (why!).

**Added**:Let $E$ and $F$ be fields. Suppose there exists an injective ring homomorphism $f:F\to E$. Then by isomorphism theorem, $f(F) \cong F/\ker(f) = F$. Thus, $f(F)$ is a subfield of $E$ that is isomorphic to $F.$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the monomorphism criterion, can you explain why that suffices to show that $K$ is a subfield of $E$?

Comment: @A.B monomorphism means injective Homomorphism.

Comment: Right, but why does that imply what we want? I haven't come across any such statement relating field extensions and monomorphisms in my text yet.

Comment: @A.B see I added above.

Answer (score 1):

We need the operations of $K$ to be those of $E$ restricted to $K$.  But we have that the operations of both $E$ and $K$ are the restrictions of those of $F$.  Thus, the operations of $K$ restricted to $E$ are the restriction of the operations of $F$ to $E$, restricted to $K$.

But  isn't that the same as the restriction of the operations of $F$ to $K$? Both $E$ and $K$ have their operations inherited from $F$.

It's a mouthful, but appears to be yes.

---

In terms of morphisms, you have a (necessarily injective, because fields have no nontrivial ideals) morphism from $K$ to $F$ (inclusion).  But, actually, the range of that morphism is contained in $E$.  So we have the required morphism from $K$ to $E$.  So $K$ is a subfield of $E$.